# Joining multiple Tables in Oracle gives out duplicated records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am a newbie to sql. I have three tables `mr1,mr2,mr3`. `Caseid` is the primary keys in all these tables. I need to join all these table columns and display result.
Problem is that i dont know which join to use.
when i joined all these just like below query:

```
select mr1.col1,mr1.col2,mr2.col1,mr2.col2,mr3.col1,mr3.col2
from mr1,mr2,mr3
where mr1.caseid = mr2.caseid
and mr2.caseid = mr3.caseid;
```

it displays 4 records, eventhough the maximum number of records is two, which is in table `mr2`.
records are duplicated, can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: It seems highly likely that `caseid` is not the primary key of all three tables.  It may be part of a compound primary key.  It wouldn't make sense to have three tables each with `caseid` as the primary key-- that would imply that all three tables are related to each other 1:1 which would mean that you should really only have 1 table.

Comment: No way. If `caseid` columns are the PKs, in **all 3** tables, no way this query will return 4 rows.

Comment: my bad guys, caseid is not primary key , its foriegn key for all three tales.
Casetable is the table with caseid as primary key.

Comment: Stop using implicit joins. They are a SQL anti[pattern and very poor coding technique. Use explicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct will do it but it's not the correct approch. 
You need to add another join (mr1.caseid = mr3.caseid) because mr2 and mr3 rows must be related to the same row in mr1, otherwise you end up with 2 pairs, onde for each tabled joined to your primary table (mr2).
First answer in SO, so forgive me if it wasn't that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your tables are in a one-to many relationship. When you join them, it is expected that the number of rows will go up unless you take steps to limit the records returned. How to fix depends on the meaning of the data.

If all the fields are exactly the same, then adding DISTINCT will fix the problem. However, it may be faster, depending on the size of the tables and the number of records you are returning, to use a derived table to limit the records in the join to only one from the table with multiple records.

If at least one of the fields is different however, then you need to know **the business rule** that will allow you to pick the correct record. It might be accomplished by adding a where clause or by using an aggregate function and group by or even both. This really depends on the meaning of the result set  which is why you need to ask further question in your own organization as they are the only ones who will know which of the multiple records is the correct one to pick from the perspectives of the people who will be using the results of the query. Further, the business might actually want to see all of the records and you have no problem at all.